# Displaying Excel Page in Iframe not possible

Tags: html, excel, iframe

I am trying to display an excel spreadsheet inside a webpage using iframe. I need the page embedded inside the webpage and not Opening on a different window. Here are the two a[proaches I have tried:

Approach 1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<IFRAME frameBorder=0 iframe
name="iframe" height=700 marginHeight=0 marginWidth=0
scrolling=auto
src="REVENUE.xls" width=100%></IFRAME>

</body>
</html>
```

The above opens the Excel in A different Window;

Approach 2:

```
<!--webbot bot="HTMLMarkup" startspan -->

<IFRAME src="REVENUE.xls" width="600" height="300" hspace="0"
vspace="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></IFRAME>

<!--webbot bot="HTMLMarkup" endspan -->
```

Same case to the second Approach. Is it a Problem with My Browser or what I am using Mozilla fireFox and excel 2003.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was possible, years ago, when browser security was laxxer, and when one of Office's selling-points was its COM/OLE base that allows entire Office applications to be hosted within other applications (not only each other, but also from within MS Binder, Visual Studio, and of course: Internet Explorer).

Times change. I understand Office 2003 is the last version of Office that can be hosted within IE, but only up to IE6 (maybe 7?), and I think it only works on intranet sites too.

The best option, moving-forward, is to use SharePoint Office Web Apps if you're a Microsoft shop on a LAN, or Google Docs, both of which allow for the embedding (and editing) of documents in web-pages.